# Allow scrolling EditText and swiping ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-viewpager

I have an EditText (vertically scrollable) inside one of the fragments in a ViewPager (horizontally swipable).

By default, touch events inside the EditText can swipe the ViewPager but not scroll the EditText. By using the code below (which I don't really understand), touch events inside the EditText can scroll the EditText but not swipe the ViewPager:

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(! ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP));
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I simultaneously allow swiping of the ViewPager and scrolling of the EditText?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this according to the solution given [here](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/handle-scrollable-views-or-controls-in-another-scrollview-in-android/).

```
pager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
       public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event) 
        {
               editText.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
           //  We will have to follow above for all scrollable contents
           return false;
        }
});
```

For the EditText, you will have to add this snippet.

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
      public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event)
       {
          // this will disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
           p_v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
           return false;
       }
});
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hi, I had to change `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` to `false` in the second snippet, and then this answer worked. Thanks :)

Comment: For me only the second snippet with `false` was needed