# ViewPager is not scrollable when touching EditText, Buttons

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I am using VerticalViewPager to scroll through two fragments, but the scrolling is not working when I'm touching EditText / Buttons... only on Views...
What can I do? Thanks

[image]

Comment: did you check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471842/allow-scrolling-edittext-and-swiping-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `android:singleLine="true"` for `EditText`, replace it with `android:maxLines="1"`

More details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19332457